# On Windows, how to convert a timestamps BEFORE 1970 into something manageable?

Tags: python, windows

Summary: "negative" timestamps on Mac work fine, but on Windows I can't convert them into something usable.

Details:
I can have a file on Windows whose modification time is, say 1904:

```
$ ls -l peter.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 sync     Administ        1 Jan  1  1904 peter.txt
```

In python:

```
>>> import os
>>> ss = os.stat('peter.txt')
>>> ss.st_mtime
-2082816000.0
```

Great. But I can't figure out how to turn that negative timestamp into a date/time string. On Mac this code works fine.

```
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(-2082816000)
datetime.datetime(1904, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

And from here I can do whatever I want in terms of formatting.

But on Windows it fails:

```
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(-2082816000)
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: timestamp out of range for platform localtime()/gmtime() function
```

And trying anything else I can think of fails:

```
>>> time.gmtime(-2082816000)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: (22, 'Invalid argument')
```

the wonderful python-dateutil package doesn't seem to have this facility. I've looked though time, calendar, and datetime module. Any help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
>>> datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(seconds=-2082816000)
datetime.datetime(1904, 1, 1, 8, 0)
```

Comment: Hugs and Kisses to you! :)

Answer (score 5):

Using Ignacio's idea, this function will convert any timestamp to a proper naive datetime object:

```
def convert_timestamp_to_datetime(timestamp):
    import datetime as dt
    if timestamp >=0:
        return dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
    else:
        return dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1) + dt.timedelta(seconds=int(timestamp))
```